# change app name in App Store and re-use the name on the new app

Tags: ios, publish

I have an app called "XX". It's already approved in the app store. For some reasons, I need to change the package name and upload the same app again.

I want to use the old name "XX". Can I change the previous app's name first(I will unpublish this app), and then use the "XX" on my app(the same app).

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the name of an app and then use that name in another app with a different bundle id (package name).

Comment: Thanks! Can I do it on the same account?

Comment: I don’t see why you wouldn’t be able to. Although it might take a minute before iTunesConnect realizes that name is not in uses anymore.